# Using JavaScript and tinyMCE, can I program a button to insert content while taking into consideration the selected text?

Tags: javascript, api, methods, insert, tinymce

This is what I have in mind...

Suppose I have **TinyMCE** open with the following text:

> Today is a sunny day.

If I want to add a text before "**sunny**" I would position the cursor before it, and click a button already programmed to insert the text. For example, the button could be programmed like this:

> editor.[insertContent](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.insertContent)('really');

and clicking it while the cursor is before "**sunny**" would give me:

> Today is a **really** sunny day.

I actually have something like this in place and it works beautifully.

Now, using the same button as above, if I have the word "**sunny**" highlighted/selected and click it, I would get:

> Today is a really **really** day.

The second "**really**" is replacing "**sunny**". And this is the expected behaviour for **[insertContent](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.insertContent)**.

Now, what if I wanted to add words before and after, for example, "**really really**". Could I highlight both words and have a button programmed to add something before and something after? Something like this:

> editor.insertContent('nice' + **existingContent** + 'sunny');

which should give me:

> Today is a **nice** really really **sunny** day

I thought that, the **args:Object** that is part of the **[inserContent](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.insertContent)** method could give me what I want, but I can't find documentation that explains what this argument is or how to use it...

Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding before really - editor.insertContent('really');?
In case of really really sunny

Comment: Check the API for a method to grab selected text and use it to build a string to insert. http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.Selection.getContent looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of `editor.selection.getContent()` and `editor.insertContent()` to get the currently selected content and then put whatever content you need back into the editor.  For example you could make a custom button like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  ...
  toolbar: ["wrapselection ...],
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('wrapselection', {
        text: 'Wrap Selection',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function () {
            editor.insertContent("<strong class='test'>" + editor.selection.getContent() + "</strong>");
        }
    });
  }
})
```